# How to pass object of object in postaman with form data

Tags: node.js, mongoose, postman

[image]bellow is the data i tried many ways but i failed to get result, please help me.

```
{
    "gstInfo": {
        "gstNumber": ,
        "SGST": "9",
        "CGST": "9",
        "IGST": "18"
    },
    "contactInfo": {
        "phoneNumber":,
        "address": "testtsetteset",
        "email": "test@gmail.com"
    },
    "codAvailable": "true",
    "gstAvailable": "true",
    "smtpInfo": {
        "hostName": "gmail",
        "smtpPort": "",
        "username": "",
        "password": "",
        "fromEmail": ""
    }
}
```

I want result in formdata with testing on postman